# window.open prevent new http request

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest

I have an asp.net web application. Some of my users report me a problem that I can’t understand why that occurred.
I have a menu on main page and users choose which services they need. When click on menu item. It open a new full screen window. I used java script for this purpose.
window.open('URL "', 'CustomPopUp', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
If they work with system for a while ( about 10 mins) and open / close several pages,  in some times, when they click on menu Item a new blank page open but without any content.
Also If they try to open a new window ( new url inside my project or outside) also the new window can’t connect to server.
I use fildder , and understand that in this case client machine don’t send any request to server.
If I close all open browser window, and open again. The problem solved and it will work for another minutes.
I check this by IE and firefox, I have more problem by IE but sometimes firefox do this also.

Would you help me to find a solution?

Thanks